# iOS Blueooth LE data without pairing

Tags: ios, bluetooth

We are investigating Bluetooth in iOS with a device we have and how to get around the issue that under iOS you cannot programmatically pair devices without prompting the user for a PIN. And cannot programmatically unpair either.

With a Fitbit, you can use it in a mode where it is not paired with the iPhone (for full notifications you do pair). But data still syncs periodically.

Does anyone know how this is being done?  We've tried using background advertisement scanning, but that rarely brings in new data even though our device sends beacon style advertisements with changing payload data.

The Fitbit can operate in a connected but not paired mode and the iOS app still receive data updates.  How?

Is the app waking from an event and then connecting out to the device periodically, or is it doing something else?

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Whether the peripheral is paired or not does not matter, iOS will behave (mostly) the same regardless. It is you (who create the peripheral) that decides if Bluetooth pairing is required or not. Basically you set permissions on the characteristics and if the iOS device reads a characteristic that requires pairing then you send an event "insufficient pairing" back to iOS. iOS will then initiate the pairing.

Comment: Maybe Fitbit send some data in advertising packages?